# Correctly compositing linear RGB elements over log footage

Tags: after-effects, colorspace, footage

I have some water splash elements I need to composite over log footage in After Effects before sending it to the colorist for grading.

As I understand, the correct workflow is to convert the log footage with Cineon Converter to linear, composite the elements, and then I guess pre-compose everything and convert it *back* to log with Cineon Converter and export it?
I'm not sure about this and all tutorials I could find are pretty vague.

(For the output format I use Cineform 10-bit YUV).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask the colorist if they'd prefer log or not. If you're exportign 10 bit yuv you should be ok without converting it. You could also export as say a 16-bit tiff sequence if you want to make sure that there's lots of room for grading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll ask the colorist, but you're saying, in general, I don't need to convert it back to log at the end?

Comment: No, it just adds extra processing. As long as what you output has a neutral grade and enough bit-depth to give the colourist the dynamic range to adjust it.